# Can I make a purely voice driven app in Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I want to create an Expo app for ios that will say something, and wait for my reply, via headphones. The headphones part is immaterial but it indicates what I want... which is for this to run while my phone is locked and in my pocket. Once I have replied, the app would proceed. I have built Expo apps but I am unsure of whether an app can still interact with me via audio and the microphone in this way while the phone is locked. Also, I don't know if Expo has introduced this sort of capability. I also don't know if React Native (i.e. ejected Expo apps) can do this sort of thing. The lack of apps that truly interact in this way (not via Siri etc) are far and few between so I'm assuming it's a hard problem to solve. I would be just as happy if I could have a browser page running on the device do the same thing, but I'm pretty sure webpages can't play audio and wait for replies when a phone is locked. Is any of this possible at this point?

I did research this online, just to be clear. I wasn't able to find an answer so I came here. I mention this because this whole post does have that 'can you research this for me' vibe. I'm just hoping someone has knowledge of what is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a page in the expo documentation that says when not to use expo, and the following is in there:

> **The SDK doesn't support all types of background code execution**
>
> *Background execution is the ability to run code when the app is not foregrounded or the device is sleeping. We support background geolocation (including geofencing) and background fetch, but we do not yet support background audio with the operating-system playback controls and you cannot handle push notifications in the background. This is a work in progress.*

You can take a look at it [here](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/why-not-expo/).

I think you can do it in React Native though, however I can't say if there is a library to do it, so you can try creating your own with native code. You can see how [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android) for android and [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios) for ios.

Comment: Ah ok, bummer. I like Expo so much. I remember the big Expo dealbreaker was no background geo and that it was a big deal when they added that. So I should have been able to deduce the answer, I guess. Oh man. I guess I'll have to walk out into the world of regular ol' React Native. Maybe. I'll look at those docs... maybe React Native will be fairly limited in this regard too. That'd be the end of this ambition for me... not going to go into Swift or whatever is going on now.

Comment: Hey man, I have never needed to do this kind of stuff before, so I may know the same thing as you about it. Maybe someone will appear with a better answer soon, don't give up! ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm realizing that voice control is really the wild west. Siri and so on are the main routes, but they only support canned activities the handset/OS maker wants you to use. And I find the delay annoying while they send the voice to the servers. The other reason I suppose is that they need to accommodate a billion users and their speaking style and so on. It seems that if I could have the same capability I could get it to recognize my voice on the device and provide a much quicker response, and also be customizable.  This is likely coming, I'm guessing.

Comment: Interesting... https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/05/21/enable-disable-voice-control-iphone... but they obviously want us to use Siri.